# How are all users now set to inactive?

Tags: login, account, wp-login-form

My client, while working on his WP blog yesterday, was doing some cleanup and claims he just removed an unused admin account. The next time he went to login, the login page rejected his account saying "Inactive Account". At this point, he calls me to let me know and I attempt to login as well - now my account says "Inactive Account".

What can cause this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Wordpress doesn't have 'inactive users', it must be done by a plugin or custom code. you got a list of plugins which it could be?

Comment: As janw says, likely a plugin. I would personally log on to FTP; download all of the plugins to your local machine (to make sure they're backed up!) then delete the plugins from the server. See if you can log in, then upload the plugins one by one until your account becomes inactive - you'll then know which is causing the problems. Alternatively it could be an issue with your theme - possibly `functions.php` if you've written some custom code in there.

Comment: Go into your databse with phpMyAdmin (or whatever you use) and check if he deleted _all_ users. Btw: **NEVER EVER GIVE A CLIENT FULL ADMIN ACCESS!** :P

Comment: I agree to the above statements; we're moving him from Shared Wordpress Blog Hosting to true web hosting, this way we have ftp support and can access the mySQL database. I'm going to see if Network Solutions has a backup so they can revert the site. I've since learned the client also hit update on everything (oops) resulting in the broken login.

Answer (score 1):

There must be some plugin that is causing the issue, you should try disabling all the plugins and reactivating them one by one and see if you find out which plugin (or the theme?) is really causing the issue, if it doesn't work for you there is always another way.
you can create as many administrator account as you want from phpmyadmin, so [here goes the tutorial that i always follow if i ever face some issues regarding the admin accounts](http://www.dnawebagency.com/how-to-add-an-admin-user-to-the-wordpress-database),

if you want everything to be proper first delete old admin accounts (don't worry, posts won't be deleted) and create new ones.

P.S: never ever give your client the full Administrator access unless they are totally dumb :-D 
you do realize what is the reason for that ;)

Comment: The members plugin was the culprit. I had not installed this particular plugin and it has been removed.